# React render JSX from method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In order to keep the render method of my component shorter and also avoid creating additional components I was hoping to render the HTML from a class method depending on the state like so:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            step: 'step1'
        }
    }

    handleChangeStep(step) {
        this.setState({ step: step })
    }

    step1 () {
        return (
            <>
                <h2>Step 1</h2>
                <div onClick={this.handleChangeStep('step2')}>Next Step</div>
            </>
        )
    }

    step2 () {
        return (
            <>
                <h2>Step 2</h2>
                <div onClick={this.handleChangeStep('step1')}>Previous Step</div>
            </>
        )
    }

    render () {
        return this.state.step === 'step2' ? this.step2() : this.step1();
    }
}
```

However this gives the error: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within` render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`.

Seems you can't do this and instead need to do something like (from: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

```
return this.state.step === 'step2' ? <Step1 /> : <Step2 />
```

However I don't understand why the former example isn't allowed as those two methods just return JSX so in theory should allow you to return one or the other depending on the state.

Comment: You're immediately calling those functions in the click listeners and assigning the result to the listener rather than assigning the _reference_ of the function to it which it should call when invoked. Try `onClick={() => this.handleChangeStep('step2')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with what you're describing.  You're trying to update state during a render:

```
onClick={this.handleChangeStep('step2')}
```

When `this.handleChangeStep('step2')` is invoked, state is updated.  Updating state triggers a re-render.  Which in this case would then update state again, and again, indefinitely.

I suspect you meant to pass a function reference to `onClick`, not *invoke* a function:

```
onClick={() => this.handleChangeStep('step2')}
```

Comment: Ah right... so you can in fact return JSX from a class method in the render it was an issue with the onClick syntax!

Comment: Yeah that works fine! I misunderstood the error message completely and was barking up the wrong tree.